# Step by step Guide for account linking in Amazon Alexa skill development?

Tags: account, alexa-skills-kit

I am newbie to Amazon Alexa skill development. Somehow so far i have developed the code for amazon alexa skill and able to test correctly through Simulator. Now i want to know and explore Account Linking facility on configuration page of alexa skill developer, as well how can i get use those credentials with external enterprise like twitter, facebook,google etc. So please suggest or help me step by step process for account linking ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Big Nerd Ranch tutorials [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/developing-alexa-skills-locally-with-nodejs-account-linking-using-oauth/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO0gZPeR45o). They're sanctioned by Amazon. Though it's not a complete step-by-step guide, it does a decent job covering Twitter specifically and the general process including:

- Configuring a Skill to Use Account Linking
- The OAuth protocol[s]
- Handling access tokens